# Streaming of digital input port (GPIO) in Beaglebone?

Tags: c, interrupt, beagleboneblack, gpio, interrupt-handling

Actually I've a function to monitor a GPIO on my beaglebone. I set that function to send an user signal (`SIGUSR1`) when an event occurs on a digital input port (external interrupt so) but that function has to be in a loop. I could insert that function in a thread or `fork()` it but I don't think it's elegant solution.

I'd like to know if exist any way/function/feature ready-to-use in C language to set the monitoring to run in a foreground (higher priority) without put in a loop, something like a `setitimer` which is declared only once and runs (keeps monitoring) without need to be in a loop.

I don't know if it's possible with beaglebone/linux but with PIC this feature is called by "Streaming Parallel Port" (SPP).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you monitor gpio, but to work with gpio from user space
(see https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt)
you can use select and poll, call it with minimum timeout time to time you
can work without loop, or if you use Qt/gtk you can insert check of gpio inside
event loops of this frameworks.

The second variant is to use setjmp/longjmp if you want to use only C,
without C++/boost,

also if you speak about timers you can use `man 2 alarm` to implement periodical timers,

the most simple way as for me is using pthreads, and setup thread that monitor gpio highest priority to not loose information.